# IOS UI Automation Export Traced Results

Tags: ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation

My **Instruments** will not save anything, I don't know if its bugged or what. I have selected a desired folder under **Logging** and checked **Continuous Log Results** but nothing gets saved inside it. I don't need image screenshots, I just need xml, html and pdf.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to save your test results, you are doing it correctly. the traced result of your test will create a .Plist file that you will need to save as an XML file. I used a XLT transform template to make the XML easier to read, with a table displaying the tests, as well as the pass/ fail result.

Comment: Please. Could you put here the transform template you used?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem. To solve it, You have to push the "record" button placed in the top left corner, before running your tests. After that you can push the "Export Traced Results" and get the .plist and all the screenshots.

I can used this post to generate html and pdf file from .plist:
http://blog.essencework.com/post/1728269540/xcode-uiautomation-for-test-result-report-part-2

[image]